# Should I change mysql table engine= ARCHIVE for tables created by Hibernate envers?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

In my spring application I am using hibernate envers to audit my entity changes. In my application database, these audit tables have occupied significant amount of data(90%) and containing 20 Millions of rows just for audit tables. I want to reduce this table size to reduce my database hosting cost. Ignoring special cases can you suggest me if I change the audit table engine to ARCHIVE, MySQL will compress them and will it raise any issue in my application? I am not using any data from audit tables in my application so far.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why it shouldn't work. Inserts into such tables will be slower though because MySQL has to compress rows. Why aren't you deleting old versions?